# Looping right and left sides of screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Ok so I am working on my first ever iPhone application right now. The gist of the game is that little bubbles from appear on the bottom of the screen and float to the top. Each bubble is its own node and can be dragged around by the person playing the game. Once a bubble hits the top of the screen... it is hits an edge and stays there. However, I am trying to figure out a way to make it so that when a bubble leaves either the left or right side of the screen, it will appear on the opposite side instead of hitting an edge, like in certain versions of the game snake. I want it to appear in real time too, so if half of the bubble is on the left side the other half will be on the right side. I have no idea how to do this or even what to look up in order to figure it out. so I came here.

Here is code for how I set the frame edges

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
```

Honestly I am very new to xcode, and swift, and spritekit, so I am not entirely sure what other code would be useful for solving the problems. I am kind of hoping that there is some sort of built in loop method that will make this easy to solve. If not let me know what other code would help in solving this problem.

Comment: That's a little complex for your first game app. Why don't you try having the bubble disappear from one side completely and then a new bubble appear from the other side on the same y coordinate line. Once you have mastered that, you should be able to figure out, or at least make an intelligent guess, how to do what you are asking.

Comment: I'll give you one teeny little hint. It may _look_ like the same bubble, and _act_ like the same bubble, but in reality, behind the scenes...